# how to check if the file path exisit or not

Tags: assembly, mainframe

I'm new for the assembly;  how to check if certain path (UNIX) path exist or not from IBM mainframe assembly code . 
for example I want to check the path '/user/lpd/file' path exist or not .

There is one example at IBM page

```
     MVC   BUFFERA(19),=CL19'labrec/qual/current'                   
     MVC   BUFLENA,=F'19'                                           
     SPACE ,                                                        
     CALL  BPX1STA,              Get file status                   +
           (BUFLENA,             Input: Pathname length            +
           BUFFERA,              Input: Pathname                   +
           STATL,                Input: Length of buffer needed    +
           STAT,                 Buffer, BPXYSTAT                  +
           RETVAL,               Return value: 0 or -1             +
           RETCODE,              Return code                       +
           RSNCODE),             Reason code                       +
           VL,MF=(E,PLIST)       ----------------------------------
```

But still this need to find manual the length of the parameter a

Comment: So your question is how to code or invoke `strlen` then?

Comment: yes, plus to that I'm going to check the path status using , clc   RETVAL(1),=cl1'0' ?

Answer (score 0):

When I first started learning HL/ASM, I found it handy to use a combination of the Principles of Operation and the C compiler listings.

If you are on the Unix System Services side, you can write a piece of code, e.g.

foo.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int foo(const char* str) {
  return strlen(str);
}
```

and then compile that code as:

c89 -c -Wc,list(./) foo.c

and then look at how the compiler generated the code.
You can also try -O2 to see how the optimizer might do it.
Be careful not to enable the optimizer to 'do too much', e.g. don't let it see the actual string or it'll just compute the length at compile-time

Answer (score 0):

A few points here as I noticed you haven't had any complete answers since January...

First, if your goal is to compute the length of your filename so that you can pass it as a parameter to stat() (or BPX1STA), then you have a few other issues in your code sample.

You think you want strlen() - which is really easy to implement in assembler using the zSeries "SEARCH STRING" (or SRST) instruction - but you're missing one key ingredient for this to work...C-style strings work because they're null-terminated, and in your code, where you have:

`MVC   BUFFERA(19),=CL19'labrec/qual/current'`

there's not necessarily a null terminator, so strlen isn't going to give you what you expect (depending on what follows this constant in memory). You've allocated a 19-character string, and whatever follows it is sort of a function of what's next in your code.

A better way might be to code it with more of a long buffer like this:

```
BUFFERA  DC 1024C' '
```

Then you'd be setup to handle a sequence like moving the string into this area and computing it's length with something like SRST.

IBM's example doesn't have this issue because BPX1STA doesn't require null-terminated strings, so they've skipped the idea of calculating a length dynamically and are just showing a hard-coded value. If you want to make it a bit more dynamic, you'd probably do something like allocate an arbitrarily long buffer (UNIX Services filenames can be 1024 bytes long), set the buffer to nulls, copy in the text you want - and then you can get the length with SRST and a little subtraction. It's not really difficult.

An alternate point is that many times, it's easier to call the C-runtime function versus the corresponding BPX1... assembler service. In assembler, the challenge is to make your code LE-conformant, but once you do that (and it's easy), you can simply call "stat()" just like a C-programmer would. In this case, you'd just pass it a null-terminated filename and an output buffer address, and the runtime function would do all the work.

If you're fluent in C, an easy way to write LE-conformant assembler is to write a short "main()" in C, and have it call your assembler code...this way, all the LE setup is done for you in advance, and anything available in the C runtime is now available to you in assembler. The other option is to just code the various CEE... macros in your assembler code - this is pretty simple too.